# I have a list of keys which I need to search in a directory and then print the keys which are not found

Tags: bash, loops

I am new to bash scripting. Need help.

I have a text file with 700 keys which I need to search in a folder and then return the keys which did not match

Comment: Can the keys contain spaces? What is the format of that file, one key per line? Also, by "search in a folder", you mean check if a file with that name exists under that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
file='translationDownloaded.txt'
while read line; do
    grep -sqr "$line" /Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src || echo $line
done < $file
```

`-s` suppresses error messages and `-q` suppresses normal output, so grep itself won't print anything on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to print those keys which are not present in the folder m searching. Also where you have mentioned the text_file can I give path of the folder? I have written a piece of code which reads the keys from my text file and does a grep in the folder but now I want to print the keys with aren't present in the folder. below is my code:

Comment: file='translationDownloaded.txt'
while read line; do
grep -r $line /Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src
done < $file

Comment: so "present in the folder" means that string occurs within any file under folder...
let me edit my answer

Comment: I did try with your code : file='translationDownloaded.txt'
folder='/Users/id856795/myproximus-rn/src'
for key in $file; do
    [ -e $folder ] || echo $key
done.        still not printing the keys which are not present in the folder, but the program does not give any error

Comment: `-e $folder` will always "return true", if your folder exists; I initially suggested `-e $folder/$key`, assuming you wanted to check if *a file named $key exists under $folder*

Comment: Glad to hear that; I edited the answer to hint to a more elegant (and performant) approach to make grep silent.

Comment: Hi Costi we had an interaction long back in this post :D but m back with a stupid query again. I am still not good in bash scripting and have a similar kind of requirement as of in this post. This time i have a file which contains links as below: myproximus://dashboard\
myproximus://products\
myproximus://products/MV\
want to check if these exists in my project src folder. Now i want to know to parse a file with slashes what should we careful be about???